# Unable to show Validation Error Message from model mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

My files are in this order

```
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.validate.mvc.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/responsive-table-ul-main.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

i am getting this error on page " Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined" .when i submit button or load page this error coming in console

Comment: Put your `jquery.validate` js scripts just after `jquery.min`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at bower file of jquery validation unobtrusive: https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/blob/master/bower.json

It is clear, that it depends on jquery.validate scripts. So you need to put them before jquery.validation.unobtrusive in your html, like this:

```
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.validate.mvc.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/responsive-table-ul-main.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its worked for me but  there is an issue when i feel the box and click outside anywhere it doesn't remove the validation border error css

Comment: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined this error coming in console

Comment: Try commenting out "jquery.validate.mvc.js" file